# How to get the materials from pivot table?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a tables `Materials` and `Tags` related to `many-to-many` through the additional `Material_Tag` table. Required when getting materials `Material::get ();` determine the condition of conformity tag list. If the data is in the same table, then this is done through `Material::where(...)->get();`. What if the data are in different tables and linked via `belongsToMany()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have relation belongsToMany for tags and you need to get the materials according to the tags:

```php
Material::whereHas('tags', function ($query) {
    $query->where('field', 'field name');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax will be the following:

```php
Material::whereHas('tags', function ($query) {
    $query->where(...);
})->get();
```

It's well documented, you should read about [Eloquent more](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations).